# Default and non-default values for optional arguments with plac

Tags: python

My goal is to run the script in the command line, with all the  arguments being optional and having a default value, using plac.

With no arguments: `python my_script.py`. It runs flawlessly.

With arguments: `python my_script.py -r "foobar"`. I get  `NoneType`  exceptions which suggests that the default values are being passed instead of the custom ones.

```
def my_function(param1=None, param2=3, param3=1, param4=None):
    ...

def main(p1: ("param1", 'option', 'r'), p2: ("param2", 'option', 's'), p3: ("param3", 'option', 't'), p4: ("param4", 'option', 'u')):
    my_function(p1, p2, p3, p4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import plac; plac.call(main)
```

Also failed when I tried adding a default argument in the main function:

```
(p1: ("param1", 'option', 'r')=None, ...)
```

Or in the plac call function:

```
plac.call(main(p1=None, ...)
```

Couldn't find any mention or example of this in the [docs](http://micheles.github.io/plac/) either.

**EDIT 1:**

After changing the code to:

```
def main(p1=("param1", 'option', 'r'), p2=("param2", 'option', 's'), p3=("param3", 'option', 't'), p4=("param4", 'option', 'u')):
```

I got the following error:

```
python my_script.py -r "foobar"
usage: my_script.py [-h] [arg1] [arg2] [arg3] [arg4]
my_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -r
```

And for the long parameter:

```
python my_script.py param1 "foobar"
TypeError: Expected 'param1' of type <str>. Got <class 'tuple'>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I ended up using [click library](https://click.palletsprojects.com/) instead of plac. And it's working.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-r', '--param1', default=None)
...
def my_function(param1, ...):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function()
```

Comment: colon `:` is for type annotations, `=` sign is for default arguments

Comment: as an alternative to `plac` I would recommend you to use [`click` package](https://click.palletsprojects.com/)

Comment: I decided on `click` instead as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_function(param1=None, param2=3, param3=1, param4=None):
```

looks fine. But, in main header I don't think you are trying to give default params

```
def main(p1: ("param1", 'option', 'r'), p2: ("param2", 'option', 's'), p3: ("param3", 'option', 't'), p4: ("param4", 'option', 'u')):
```

You can pass something like:

```
def main(p1= ("param1", 'option', 'r'), p2= ("param2", 'option', 's')):
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work. I got `error: unrecognized arguments: -r` for calling `-r foobar`. And got a type error being passed as a tuple instead of str for the long parameter.

Comment: I meant can you update your question with final code that ran into error?

Comment: Made the changes.

Comment: -r is unrecognized. Your script isn't expecting that. It also prints usage where you have -h but not -r

Comment: I'm using `click` and it's working, but feel free to suggest an answer to the original question. Thanks.